# R: Can you change the chart type of dyRangeSelector from the R package dygraphs

Tags: r, dygraphs

I'm using the R package **dygraphs** for creating an interactive time series chart.
I want both the main chart and the **selector** to be bar charts.
I managed to make the main graph as a bar chart.

However I'm wondering if there is a way to change the chart type of dyRangeSelector which appears below the graph. At the moment is a simple linear plot.
See below the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

```
install.packages(c("dygraphs","xts"))
library(dygraphs) 
library(xts) 

# First I create my Time series
df <- as.xts(ts(start =c(1950), end=c(2010),
                   data = runif(61,0,5)))

# Create the graph
dygraph(df, main = "Frequency") %>%
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c(min(index(df)), max(index(df))))  %>%
  dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE, plotter = 
              "function barChartPlotter(e) {
            var ctx = e.drawingContext;
            var points = e.points;
            var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);  // see     http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#toDomYCoord

            // This should really be based on the minimum gap
            var bar_width = 2/3 * (points[1].canvasx - points[0].canvasx);
            ctx.fillStyle = e.color;

            // Do the actual plotting.
            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var p = points[i];
            var center_x = p.canvasx;  // center of the bar

            ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
            bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
            ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
            bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
            }
            }")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try stepplot maybe it's not really barchart but really close and the selector is stepplot too

```
dygraph(df, main = "Frequency") %>%
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c(min(index(df)), max(index(df))))  %>%
  dyOptions(stepPlot = TRUE ,fillGraph = TRUE, fillAlpha = 0.4)
```

Comment: Thanks brunel - Yes unfortunately it's not the same but better than nothing. I also noticed a problem, whether the RangeSelector is linear or as barchart the zeroes are not represented properly. Namely the "zeroes" values do not lay on the x-axis of the RangeSelector, but they are always above it. Is there a way to solve this problem?